# Разворачивающаяся таблица

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько таблиц, как на примере.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.tbl").click(function(){
    $(this).next("tr.hide").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>
    <!-- Таблица 1 -->
<table border=1 class="">
  <tr class="tbl">
    <td>SH1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border=1>
    <tr class="tbl"><td>SH2</td></tr>
    <tr class="hide" style="display:none">
      <td>
        <table><tr><td>INFO</td></tr></table>
      </td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<!-- Таблица 2 -->
...
...
<!-- Таблица N -->
```

Как сделать, чтобы и при нажатии на "Шапка 1" либо "Шапка 2" разворачивалась "ИНФА".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table class="swtable">
    <tr class="switch"><td>Шапка 1</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Шапка 2</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="switched" style="display:none">
                    <td><table><tr><td>Инфа<td><tr></table></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('table.swtable tr.switch').click(function(){
    var n = $('tr.switch').index(this);
    $('tr.switched').eq(n).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Решение не слишком "чистое" и не слишком удобное (скорость за счет удобства). Но вы можете его доработать под себя.

**ДОБАВЛЕНО**

```
<table class="swtable">
    <tr class="switch"><td>Шапка 1</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr class="switch">
                    <td>Шапка 2</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="switched" style="display:none">
                    <td><table><tr><td>Инфа<td><tr></table></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('table.swtable tr.switch').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('table.swtable').find('tr.switched').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Что-то я туплю..этот вариант рабочий?

Comment: Вариант рабочий, отредактируйте его под себя.

Comment: Значит туплю..вставляю код и не работает, так же как и с .find

Comment: у меня не заработал. скопировал 1 в 1

Comment: Упс. Опечатался: надо tr.switched. Исправил.

Comment: js в функцию ready вынесите, а то боюсь не разберется)

Comment: Все, теперь спасибо. Буду учиться :)

Comment: Не за что). api.jQuery.com + google.ru = лучшие учебники. Ну, и я в [своем блоге][1] (реклама) тоже потихоньку начинаю описывать распространенные моменты. =)

[1]: http://v3shin.ru/2011/11/24/77/

Comment: Ну гугльщик с меня сегодня не удался, видать плохо капался. Ну а блог себе в избранное, и буду обращаться)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=1>
  <tr class="tbl" id="shp1"><td>Шапка 1</td></tr>
    <td>
      <table border=1>
    <tr class="tbl">
      <td>Шапка 2</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="hide" style="display:none">
      <td><table><tr><td>Инфа<td><tr></table></td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr#shp1").click(function(){
    $("tr.hide").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

или если id на шапка 1 не подходит:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.tbl").click(function(){
    $("tr.hide").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

Comment: во втором случает ИНФА откроется и по клику на Шапка2. потому что клик обрабатывается по классу, а класс на 2х tr. именно поэтому на шапку 1 я повесил идентификатор.
Еще как вариант можно использовать 
 $("tr.tbl:first").click(function(){...});

Comment: Извиняюсь, не так задал вопрос. Если формируется несколько таких таблиц, во всех классы одинаковые, но при нажатии "Шапка 1" и "Шапка 2" разворачивается только текущая таблица.

Comment: тогда так:  $(this).find("tr.hide").slideToggle("slow");

Comment: непонятно почему, но .find почему-то вообще не прокатывает. http://olgachan.com/1.html

Comment: приведите в порядок разметку. а то у вас там есть лишние и недостающие элементы
после закрывающего tr не может быть td...

Comment: Сори, это исправил, но результат тот же (ссылка та же)